# How to list sub-modules in teamcity SonarQube runner

Tags: maven, sonarqube, teamcity

We are building a maven project with several modules and submodules in teamcity and we would like to use sonar as well. To send the analysis we use the SonarQube Runner build step, but it requires a list of modules to include. 
Our solution looks like this:

```
Module-A
Module-B
    Sub-module-B1
    Sub-module-B2
    Sub-module-B3
Module-C
    Sub-module-C1
```

I am able to use only the modules without sub-modules in the modules field in the TeamCity runner.
The sub-modules Require some special format - **how do I specify them?**
I tried to write there

```
Module-A,Module-B/Module-B1,...
```

But then it complains about the slash delimiter.

Comment: Why not using: `mvn -Dmaven.test.failure.ignore=true -Dfindbugs.failOnError=false clean verify -Dsonar.host.url=$SONAR_HOST_URL -Dsonar.login=$SONAR_AUTH_TOKEN sonar:sonar`? This will scan all modules and send the results to SonarQube...

Comment: Because of reasons I cannot now get a authorization token :( The teamcity has a valid one.

Comment: But TeamCity should have an option to give the AUTH_TOKEN to the command line ...otherwise you have to maintain the list of modules manually which is not a good idea...cause each time you add a module you have to change the configuration in TeamCity...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way was to use the maven goal sonar:sonar afterall.